# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificado)

Tags: sql, asp, server

Me aparece el siguiente error al llamar un archivo.aspx desde un botón, soy algo nuevo en .net les agradeceria me pudieran ayudar.

Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/1fddccaf-1a6a-424c-9c32-5d43cd86ac84/error-26-sql?forum=vbes entra aqui

Comment: ¿Cadena de conexión?

Comment: Le diste una cadena de conexión y esos datos eran incorrectos.